# Heroku Scheduler - set up daily task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, twilio, scheduler, rake-task

I'm having trouble understanding Heroku's scheduler documentation.

They give this as example code, but I'm not sure what's what:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task :update_feed => :environment do
  puts "Updating feed..."
  NewsFeed.update
  puts "done."
end

task :send_reminders => :environment do
  User.send_reminders
end
```

I am hoping to use this scheduler to call method from my NotificationsController on a daily basis. I've tried modifying their code to:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task notify: :environment do
  Notifications.notify
end
```

My notifications_controller.rb looks like: 
Notice integration of Twilio's API is included...also this will be refactored down the road, but it does work in testing.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    require 'twilio-ruby'

    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_action :set_twilio_client

    $numbers = []
    User.all.select {|user| $numbers << user.phone_number}


    def daily_text
        $daily_text = ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"]
        $daily_text.sample
    end

    def notify
        message = @client.messages.create(
            from: '+1401XXXXXXX',
            to: $numbers,
            body: daily_text
            )

        render plain: message.status
    end

    private

    def set_twilio_client
        twilio_account_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
        twilio_auth_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
        @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token
    end

end
```

Maybe I need to move some stuff up to model level? Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored and moved most things into a TwilioClient model:

```
class TwilioClient
    require 'twilio-ruby'

    def initialize
        @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"], ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    end

    def notify
        @client.messages.create(
            from: '+1401XXXXXXX',
            to: all_phone_numbers,
            body: daily_text
        )
    end

    private

    def daily_text
        ["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"].sample
    end

    def all_phone_numbers
        User.pluck(:phone_number)
    end

end
```

Notifications Controller now looks like:

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

    def notify
        client = TwilioClient.new
        result = client.notify
        render plain: result.status
    end
end
```

and rake task:

```
desc "This task is called by the Heroku scheduler add-on"
task notify: :environment do
  client = TwilioClient.new
  client.notify
end
```