# Heroku Scheduler (for Daily Tasks) in Node – Proper docs?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron, scheduled-tasks

I made an app using *Cron* to scrape data which worked perfectly when done locally (inside the `/project_root/scraper/index.js` file):

```
const everyMorning = new CronJob('0 15 7 * * *', () => {
  //runScraper1(); runScraper2(); runScraper3(); (This runs at 7:15 AM)
}, null, true, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

But now that I put it on Heroku, I see that this function will basically never run, because I guess Heroku shuts the server off after some inactivity (probably an hour or so). It looks like I need to use [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler); but the docs (in [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489818/heroku-scheduler-set-up-daily-task)), which I don't know. I found tons of disjointed info about how to do this in Node, so here's what I gathered...

...

**One strategy** seems to be:

1) Create a `bin` folder and a `herokuFile`, like this: `project_root/bin/node/herokuFile` (rename `herokuFile` to whatever you want, but don't use an extension like `.js`).

2) Write the file to look like this:

```
#! /app/.heroku/node/bin/node
var start = require('./app.js');
function activateTask() {
  start();
}
activateTask();
process.exit();
```

3) Apparently I'm supposed to add `module.exports = start` to my `app.js` file or something like that... and then run `heroku run activateTask` in terminal...?

...

**Another strategy** seems to be:

a) Run `heroku addons:create scheduler:standard` to install Heroku Scheduler and then `heroku addons:open scheduler` to open the scheduler in your browser. Then in the scheduler interface, write "worker" (without node) so that it says `$ worker`, and set it to `daily`.

b) Add a file named `Procfile` (don’t change the name, don’t use an extension) in the project’s root directory. Make the Procfile say:

```
web: node app.js
worker: node herokuCron.js
```

c) Make a `herokuCron.js` file (also in `project_root/bin/node/herokuFile`), and have it say:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
function logMessage() {
  console.log('GONG! An hour has passed and herokuCron.js has activated');
}
logMessage();
```

d) ...?

...

Needless to say, neither of these approaches worked for me, and I don't understand why (I'm just a junior dev). I have looked everywhere but I can't figure out how to run my simple daily task function.